# Blender 2.8 rig not fully updating on render

Tags: armature

I know 2.8 is still in beta mode so I was just wondering if anyone else is having this same issue and if it will be fixed at some point. My rig has lots of drivers attached to it. For some reason the 2.8 version of blender is really slow at updating the location of the mesh around the armature when it moves. Sometimes I have to double click the time line for it to fully update dependencies. When I go to do a render, it can forget sometimes also. Like I said, I know it's a beta, but has anyone else noticed a slow armature registry and is this a known issue? If so, I hope they fix it because my rig works great in 2.79 Didn't they do a full rebuild of the bone system?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by collision, if you have multiple collision on a armature it causes this problem. normally the armature should have priority but something gets mixed up there.

As soon as I remove all collisions it worked like expected.